# Como enviar queries simultaneamente para testar eficiência das Transactions no MySQL?

Tags: mysql, innodb, integridade

Tenho uma tabela *InnoDB* no MySQL onde armazeno o saldo da conta de um usuário. Para dar um `UPDATE` no saldo eu utilizo *Transactions* para evitar que duas ou mais queries tentem dar `UPDATE` de forma simultânea e acabe corrompendo o valor do saldo.

Utilizando PHP de preferencia, ou alguma outra ferramenta especifica para isso, qual a melhor maneira de realizar testes de queries, por exemplo, enviar 10 queries de forma simultânea solicitando `UPDATE` da tabela para testar a eficiência do uso das *Transactions* e ter certeza que meu algoritmo não vai corromper os dados?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você diz preferencia usar uma ferramenta pronta para o teste,

- Usaria a ferramenta mysqlslap como ultimo teste, porque assim você acaba testando somente a parta do banco de dados, é um teste que valida sim a parte das transações até o fim, mas...
- Daria mais valor a um teste customizado, seria mais eficiente fazer arquivos em php com as mesmas instruções e rodar tudo junto através de uma única linha de comando, isso irá criar a concorrência que deseja para exaustar o seu teste que seria mais próximo de uma simulação real do seu próprio cenário porque pode aparecer problemas de programação no php antes mesmo de chegar ao banco de dados, rodando somente o teste no banco fica faltando testar esse comportamento da programação que você fez no php

Comment: Seria uma boa prática então simular centenas ou até milhares de HTTP request utilizando o Apache AB? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html

Comment: sim, com o apache benchmark você já consegue medir os request completados, os que falharam, o tempo de resposta, e isso já será considerando o tempo das consultas, claro que dependendo dos resultados precisará ajustar as consultas no BD.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar o [`mysqlslap`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlslap.html) para testar suas *transactions*. Crie um arquivo `.sql` com os casos que você deseja testar. Seu *script* seria algo como:

```
> mysqlslap --concurrency=5 --iterations=5 --query=query.sql --delimiter=";"
```

Onde `concurrency` seria o número de clientes simultâneos e `iterations` a quantidade de *queries* que cada cliente irá executar.